# Find Angle between 2 polylines

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I am drawing MKPolyLines between 2 sets of coordinates on a MKPolyLineView in MkMapView. One line is the actual route travelled from one point to the other, while the other line is the shortest distance between the 2 points. I have successfully drawn the 2 sets of lines. Now I need to find the angle with direction in between the 2 lines. Despite my efforts I have not been able to come up with anything helpful. Help needed.

This is how I have drawn polylines.

```
self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsToUse count:[array count]];
self.straightLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:straightLinePoints count:2];

[self.map addOverlay:self.routeLine];
[self.map addOverlay:self.straightLine];

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
if(overlay == self.routeLine){
// ylineView *polyLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.polyLine];
polyLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
polyLineView.lineWidth = 2;
polyLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
polyLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
return polyLineView;
}
else{
    polyLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.straightRouteLine];
    polyLineView.lineWidth = 2;
    polyLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    polyLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return polyLineView;
}
}
```

Comment: There is no single angle between two lines if they are not both straight lines. Since both of your lines go to and from the same point what angle are you talking about? Maybe provide a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code that does just this in Python. I can post the code later when I get home, but it looks something like this:

```
angle = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / PI;
```